# Accessing specific button inside of a list

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a GUI for my program and faced a problem trying to access text from a clicked `QPushButton`.

The problem is, when I use for-loop to iterate through a list of buttons `button.clicked.connect(function)` processes every click as a click on the last item (at least, I think so).

Here's sample code

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout
import sys


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # main window
    win = QMainWindow()
    win.setGeometry(100, 100, 460, 80)
    win.setWindowTitle("My great app")

    # layout
    box = QWidget(win)
    box.setGeometry(0, 0, 460, 80)
    layout = QHBoxLayout(win)
    box.setLayout(layout)

    btns = []

    # creating 10 buttons
    for i in range(10):
        btn = QPushButton(str(i+1), box)
        btns.append(btn)
        layout.addWidget(btns[i], i)

    # accessing buttons text
    for btn in btns:
        btn.clicked.connect(lambda: print(btn.text()))

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you run the program and click on any button it will print "10" every time.

Answer (score 2):

You should read here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#details and here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, \
    QPushButton, QHBoxLayout


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # main window
    win = QMainWindow()
    win.setGeometry(100, 100, 460, 80)
    win.setWindowTitle("My great app")

    # layout
    box = QWidget()                               #(win)
    box.setGeometry(0, 0, 460, 80)
    layout = QHBoxLayout(box)                     #(win)
#    box.setLayout(layout)                        # ---
    win.setCentralWidget(box)                     # +++

    btns = []

    # creating 10 buttons
    for i in range(10):
        btn = QPushButton(str(i+1)) #, box)
        btns.append(btn)
        layout.addWidget(btns[i], i)

    # accessing buttons text
#       btn.clicked.connect(lambda: print(btn.text()))                 # ---
        btn.clicked.connect(lambda ch, text=btn.text(): print(text))   # +++

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: is this applied for all kinds of widgets, like using all the parameters that the signal sends + the parameter that we want in the lambda function?